# Solving this recurrence relation representing constant-power loads on a resistive cable

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Given the following:
$$\begin{align}
v_n&=v_{n-1}-r\sum_{i=n}^m \frac p{v_i}\\
v_0&=V
\end{align}$$
where:
$$\begin{align}
m\ge n\ge 0\;&:\;m,\,n\in\mathbb {N_0}\\
V,\,r,\,p,\,m\;&:\;\text{constants}
\end{align}$$
I'm trying to determine an expression for $v_n$ that does not involve $v_n$ on the right-hand side. (As presented above, the definition is circular.)

---

*Mathematica*'s [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) function can solve this for a specific value of $m$ if I write out the equations. For example:
$$\begin{align}
v_0&=V\\
v_1&=v_0-r\,(\frac p{v_1}+\frac p{v_2}+\frac p{v_3})\\
v_2&=v_1-r\,(\frac p{v_2}+\frac p{v_3})\\
v_3&=v_2-r\,\frac p{v_3}
\end{align}$$
Solved symbolically, the result is pages and pages long and involves many [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. Numerically, with $V=48$, $p=36$, and $r=3$, the result is:
$$\begin{align}
v_0&=48.0000\\
v_1&=36.7473\\
v_2&=28.4335\\
v_3&=23.9181
\end{align}$$
If possible, I would like to derive a more general solution (for arbitrary $m$) that is compact enough to represent reasonably in Excel (or maybe C). It doesn't *have* to be a closed-form expression (though that is prefered); it could be a simple algorithm.

In trying to solve this, I've discovered recurrence relations (and *Mathematica*'s [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) function), which this looks a lot like to me, but I'm not versed in those, and I have no idea how to apply those to solving this problem (or whether that is even possible).  (Based on what I've seen so far, recurrence relations seem to deal mainly with infinite sequences, whereas this is very much a finite, but arbitrary-length, sequence, and each node depends on the values of the complete sequence.)

---

**Background**

This is an electronics problem.

I have a number of constant-power loads at regular intervals along a cable, and I want to determine the voltage at each load, taking into account the resistive voltage drop of the cable.

Here's a schematic representation:

[image]

Because the loads are constant-power, the current they draw increases as their voltage decreases. The increased current, in turn, decreases the voltage (through the resistive cable losses), which further increases the current.

Comment: In the course of putting together an answer for this, I noticed something while putting together numerics in Mathematica: the example system you give has two sets of real solutions, not one. This moreover appears to be generically true for the model you provide. Is there some further constraint which eliminates the second solution set?

Comment: @Semiclassical Usually, the solution with the greatest vm is the "correct" solution. For my example, the second solution has v3 = 18.5406, so it was discarded in favor of the solution with v3 = 23.9181. However, this is probably not _always_ appropriate. Mathematically, it's probably best to generate the full set of solutions and then pick the appropriate solution set based on application knowledge.